# Read multiple strings from a file and store it in a single character array

Tags: c

I want to store a line of string in a single line to a single charracter array such as, Let file content to be this:

```
1 Bar of Chocolate 45
```

I want to store "Bar of Chocolate" to a single character array when using fscanf. When I try fscanf it only reads "Bar" as a single string.

Comment: Please show your code. We can't point out what the problem may be if we can't see the code.

Comment: You need to use the `%[` format. Or read the whole line and then manually find the first and last space to get the sub-string in between (which is my personal recommendation).

Comment: When I get the whole line, how can I take integers as integers, strings as strings?

Comment: [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to get the first number. When you get the first integer you also get a pointer to the first space. Then [`strrchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) to find the last space. Then [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) to copy the sub-string between the first and last space (skipping leading and trailing spaces first). Finally another `strtol` call to get the last number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following program can be used as starting point:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {


    int nb1;
    int nb2;
    char s1[50];

    int rc;

    printf("Please enter data:");
    rc = scanf("%d %[a-zA-Z ] %d", &nb1, s1, &nb2);

    printf("\nMatched input items=%d\n", rc);    
    printf("\nEntered data: nb1=%d s1=%s nb2=%d\n", nb1, s1, nb2);    

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
./scanf
Please enter data:1 Bar Of Chocolate 45

Matched input items=3

Entered data: nb1=1 s1=Bar Of Chocolate  nb2=45
```

Comment: It takes unwanted characters too such as  "½¼¡«»░▒▓│┤ÁÂÀ©╣║╗╝¢¥┐└┴┬├─┼ãÃ╚╔╩╦╠═╬¤ºªÊËÈÍÎÏ┘┌█▄¦Ì▀└┴┬├─┼ãÃ╚╔╩╦╠═╬¤ºªÊËÈÍ¸Ï┘┌█▄¦Ìş^9=¤Ov"